# UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xa0' in position 37: ordinal not in range(128)

Tags: python, xlrd

Getting this error while executing below code:

```
def csvFromExcel(path):
    'This is for converting Delights.xlsx sheets into sheetName.csv '
    wb = xlrd.open_workbook(path)
    print wb.nsheets
    sheetNames = []
    sheetNames = wb.sheet_names()
    print sheetNames
    for sheetName in sheetNames:
        sh = wb.sheet_by_name(sheetName)
        csvFile = open("processed/"+sheetName+'.csv', 'wb')
        wr = csv.writer(csvFile, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)

        for rownum in xrange(sh.nrows):
            wr.writerow(sh.row_values(rownum))
        csvFile.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    path = 'toBeProcess/Delights.xlsx'
    csvFromExcel(path)
```

At this point i'm getting error: `wr.writerow(sh.row_values(rownum))`

Does anyone have any idea how to fix it.

Comment: Where does it fail? You have to set the encoding to utf-8

Comment: At which point in the program it occurs? Do you have non-breaking space in some row or sheetName?

Comment: `wr.writerow(sh.row_values(rownum))` at this point

Comment: @xbirkettx where i need to set utf-8 ?

Comment: There are literally hundreds of postings asking similar questions, take a look at some of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved it by using `encode('utf-8')`

```
def csvFromExcel(path):
    'This is for converting Delights.xlsx sheets into sheetName.csv '
    wb = xlrd.open_workbook(path)
    print wb.nsheets
    sheetNames = []
    sheetNames = wb.sheet_names()
    print sheetNames
    for sheetName in sheetNames:
        sh = wb.sheet_by_index(2)
        csvFile = open("processed/"+sheetName+".csv", 'wb')
        wr = csv.writer(csvFile, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)

        for rownum in xrange(sh.nrows):
            wr.writerow(
                 list(x.encode('utf-8') if type(x) == type(u'') else x
                      for x in sh.row_values(rownum)))
        csvFile.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    path = 'toBeProcess/Delights.xlsx'
    csvFromExcel(path)
```

Comment: you may need to encode "processed/"+sheetName+".csv" as well just in case.